# How to show that this function is continuous but not differentiable at x=0?

Tags: limits, continuity

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x\tan^{-1}(1/x), &x\neq 0\\
0,&x=0
\end{cases}
$$
How do i find $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x\tan^{-1}(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} x\tan^{-1}(x)$ in order to prove its continuous?

Comment: $|x \arctan (1/x)|\leq |x\cdot \pi /2|.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

you can use L'Hospital rule for
$$
\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}
$$

Comment: Or substitute $x=1/y$ and find $\lim_{|y|\to \infty}(\tan^{-1}y)/y$.

Answer (score 1):

For continuity at $x=0$, you would need to show $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0)$.
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\arctan \frac{1}{x} =0 $$
holds, because the function $\arctan$ is bounded.

For differentiability at $x=0$, you need to show
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\arctan\frac{1}{h}}{h}\in\mathbb R $$
Does it exist, though? What happens when $h\to 0^+$ and $h\to 0^-$?